# Why won't this MOSFET driver work?

Tags: mosfet-driver

I built this simple MOSFET driver and it won't work.

The MOSFET used is [AOD442](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AOI442.pdf). Supply+ is 24V. The load is a vacuum pump. The control signal is from a Raspberry Pi 4B. I took a few measurements and when I turn on the control signal I can see 12V on the gate pin as expected. However, the pump does not turn on. I connected the pump across the supply separately just to check if it works and it does. Completely stumped! Why won't this work?

[image]

Comment: So, the motor is connected between `SUPPLY+` and `OUT`, yes?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 The coil is a 24V vacuum pump. Not sure I understand what you mean by flyback protection on the gate.

Comment: @electrophile Does it switch on an LED in place of the motor? (A 4K7 series resistor should be enough.)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I think that says "COLL" (for collecter?) not coil. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: What is the drain voltage when the MOSFET is "on", with its gate at 12V? (and with the pump connected, of course)

Comment: I made a really really really stupid mistake. I connected the pump between `MOUT` and `GNDPWR` instead of `SUPPLY+` and `MOUT`. It works now.

Comment: @electrophile I was concerned when I asked about the connection because I saw *two* GND terminals on the connector when it only needs one, but it needs two SUPPLY+ terminals.

Comment: Your terminals are misleading... if you connect the motor's positive to `SUPPLY+`, where does the power supply go? If I see a clamp labeled like this, I would connect the motor between `OUT` and `GND` and the PSU between `SUPPLY` and `GND`, but that'd obviously be wrong.

Comment: The lesson I learnt is always ask for a photo.

Comment: @electrophile If you have a solution (connected the pump between the wrong pins) then please post that as an answer instead of buried in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I made a stupid error. I kept connecting the coil between `OUT` and `GNDPWR` when it should have been `SUPPLY+` and `MOUT`. All is well now. The schematic works fine.